# archivo sudoers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vi, sudo

Hola amigos me surgio una duda con respecto a poner unos permisos con ayuda de visudo ¿Me podrian hechar una mano?

La pregunta puntual es: ¿Porque se usa (ALL:ALL) quiero decir si el primero antes de los dos puntos es **"COMO QUIEN"** lo que yo entiendo es que deberia seguir esta forma **QUIÉN DÓNDE=(COMO QUIÉN)**.

Entonces que quiere decir el ALL despues de los 2 puntos podrian ponerme algun ejemplo gracias por leerme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formato:

```
quién dónde = (como_quién) qué
```

Ejemplo:

```
USER   HOST=(ASUSER)  COMMAND  # uso

root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL    # como se veria
```

Considerando que ALL significa "todos", esto quiere decir que la regla aplica al usuario root, en todos los hosts, root puede ejecutar comandos como todos los usuarios y se pueden ejecutar todos los comandos.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Bro gracias por tu respuesta pero entonces sigo sin entender que quiere decir (ALL:ALL) ? osea que primero como root y despues como grupo ?

Comment: el primer all es: "user" podrá usar comandos de cualquier usuario.

Comment: el segundo all es: si el anterior "ALL" permitía usar comandos de usuarios, éste lo hará de grupos.

Comment: de dentro del parentesis

Comment: https://prnt.sc/22innim

Comment: Te pase una imagen donde se especifican mejor

Comment: Gracias bro entonces solo para confirmar (ALL:ALL) el primer ALL sera para ejecutar todos los comandos y el segundo todos los comandos  que pueden ejecutar todos los grupos es asi¿?

Comment: el primero es ejecutar como todo los usuarios y el segundo como todo los grupos pero  si xd

Comment: Muchas gracias en verdad bro :D